# Screen flickering in Ubuntu 16.04.lts

Tags: 16.04, screen, flicker

Recently I am having a problem of flickering screen on my Lenovo laptop where I have installed ubuntu 16.04 . It had also happened a couple of months ago, but was fixed automatically the next day after I connected my laptop to external monitor through HDMI where just mouse was flickering and same thing happened to my laptop screen the next day for a while and was fixed automatically. But the problem is now happening consistantly and is not solved. What can I do for that ?

Comment: What is your laptop model ? Try to find graphics drivers.

Comment: My laptop model is Lenovo ideapad 300. I tried to update the graphics drivers but failed. When I check the driver  it says - 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium 
Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3904
 Kernel driver in use: i915

The screen is fine now , and it happened automatically. 
Actually I updated everything that were pending in the system this morning and now it is working good. Does that have any connections ?

Comment: I also suspect the newly updated WPS office which is very similar to the windows MS office package. Is the graphics too heavy for my drivers ? Because the screen flickering happened each time I frequently used the newly updated package. Is that possible ?

Comment: Nice to hear that things work good now .